# Error or gap in "Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series", by Apostol

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

My question concerns Apostol's Chapter 7, [Kronecker's Theorem with Applications](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0999-7_7). It's Theorem 7.11, page 156.

I’m attaching the proof in question. There is a lot going on, but I’ve highlighted the issue with red boxes.

[image]
In the first box, $s$ is a complex number and from the context, it seems clear that its imaginary part is the $t$ obtained a moment earlier, which itself depends on the integer $n$. In this first box, Apostol obtains a certain integer $n_0$ and a moment later (second box) picks some $n≥n0$. The third box simply restates the issue, namely that $n$ depends on $n_0$ which depends on $t$ which depends on $n$.

[image]

This circle can be broken if we can pick $n_0$ independently of $t$ and my conjecture is that $t=0$ is the “worst” for the convergence of the infinite product in the first red box (we could then use the value of $n_0$ obtained from $t=0$ with any imaginary part $t$). It’s easy to show that the difference between any individual term of the product and 1 is maximal when $t=0$, but I don’t see how it follows that convergence is slowest with $t=0$. Possibly it’s an elementary fact in the theory of the zeta function. I'd be grateful for any tips!

Comment: In the first box, it is not hard to show $n_0$ is independent of $t=\Im s$ (depends only on $\varepsilon$ and $\sigma=\Re s$). This relates to $\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-\sigma}$ converging absolutely. I think that resolves your issue.

Comment: (1/2) I realize that in the last paragraph you have a similar idea, but didn't have the details, so let me fill them in. No number theory is needed. Let $A_{n,s}:=\prod_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(1-p_k^{-s})$ and we'll show $|\log A_{n,s}|<\varepsilon$ if $n$ is sufficiently large (independently of $t$). The branch of the logarithm being used is the one where $-\log(1-z)=\sum_{i \ge 1} z^i/i$. Observe $|p_k^{-s}| \le 2^{-\sigma} < 1$. Using $-\log(1-z)=z+O(|z|^2)$ for $|z| \le 2^{-\sigma} < 1$ (where the implied constant depends on $\sigma$), (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) we see $-\log A_{n,s} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} p_k^{-s} + O(\sum_{k=n+1} |p_k^{-2s}|)$. By the triangle inequality this is $\ll \sum_{k \ge n+1} p_k^{-\sigma} \ll \int_{n}^{\infty} t^{-\sigma} = \frac{n^{1-\sigma}}{\sigma-1}$, which can be made smaller than $\epsilon$ if $n$ is large enough depending only on $\sigma$.

Comment: Looks great. Thanks